# Drupal 6: Theme "Download Count" module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using the "Download Count" module.  It currently outputs a link to the file to be counted and below that the number of times it has been downloaded.  I want to be able to have these as independent variables that I can theme.

On this page http://drupal.org/node/923690 the author says:

"Another option would be to create a preprocess_node function in the template.php file and create some variables in there that you could print in the node."

I'm not sure how to do this.  Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I figured this out.  I simply took the theme function

`THEME_download_count_formatter_download_count($element)`

and stuck it in my template.php file and themed the function as I needed.